# Adding values using LINQ to an object property with a Dictionary property

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a dataset which returns a couple of contact information in `string(Phone, mobile, skype)`. I created an object with a Dictionary property where i can put the contact information in a key value pair. The problem is, I am assigning the values of the object using Linq. Hope somebody can help. Here is my code:

```
public class Student
    {
        public Student()
        {
            MotherContacts = new ContactDetail();
            FatherContacts = new ContactDetail();
        }
        public ContactDetail MotherContacts { get; set; }
        public ContactDetail FatherContacts { get; set; }
    }

public class ContactDetail
{
    public ContactDetail()
    {
        Items = new Dictionary<ContactDetailType, string>();
    }
    public IDictionary<ContactDetailType, string> Items { get; set; }

    public void Add(ContactDetailType type, string value)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            Items.Add(type, value);
        }
    }
}

public enum ContactDetailType
{
    PHONE,
    MOBILE
}
```

Here's how I assign value to the Student object:

```
    var result = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
    var insuranceCard = result.Select(row => new Student()
        {
             MotherContacts.Items.Add(ContactDetailType.PHONE, row.Field<string>("MotherPhone"),
             MotherContacts.Items.Add(ContactDetailType.MOBILE, row.Field<string>("MotherMobile")
        }).FirstOrDefault();
```

The compiler says that the `MotherContacts` is not recognized in the context. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code should look like:

```
var insuranceCard = result.Select(row => 
{ 
     var s = new Student();
     s.MotherContacts.Items.Add(ContactDetailType.PHONE, row.Field<string>("MotherPhone");
     s.MotherContacts.Items.Add(ContactDetailType.MOBILE, row.Field<string>("MotherMobile");
     return s;
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

You are using the object initializer syntax in a wrong way. The correct use is:

`new Student{MotherContacts = value}` where value must be a `ContactDetail`.

Comment: That does the trick. It got me confused since I am adding values to the Items which is a property of the ContactDetails. Thank you very much

Comment: @KatrinaRivera If it was useful please mark the answer and vote.